# Weird behaving of link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

So I have been playing around with this pen: codepen.io/oknoblich/pen/ELfzd

If you wrap a div with a link like this:

```
 <a href="#">
  <div>
    <img src="link-to-image" />
  </div>
 </a>
```

image gets resized. Why is that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pratikloda mentioned above, the `>` directive requires that specified elements be immediate children (nothing between them in the DOM hierarchy). By adding the `<a href>` , the `<div>` is no longer an immediate child of `.gallery`, as the `<a>` is between them.

Removing the `>` from lines 13, 31, 38, 42 (or, adding the `> a >` between `.gallery` and `div`, as done on line 31), will solve the problem.

[Revised Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOXEBq)

Comment: Oh yeah! How could I have missed that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not changing the CSS,

```
.gallery > div{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 padding: 5px;
}

.gallery > div > img {
 display: block;
 }

.gallery > div:hover {
  z-index: 1;
 }
```

">" this sign means that the CSS will apply to only those div who are directly inside .gallery so you need toedit the css to .gallery > a > div and so on.